# Как добавить и зачем нужны BuildVariants?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit

Вот я разбираюсь с тем как писать тесты для андроид и вот тут есть такое [учебное пособие](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/#6) в течении обьяснений мы переключаем `BuildVariants`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Только вот я так до конца не понял зачем нужны разные версии? Почему
   бы не собрать все в одну?
2. Как добаволять в этот выпадающий список свои названия и
   конфигурации?

**ПРАВКА**

Немного понял исходя из ответа @temq как это работает только хотел бы уточнить еще несколько вопросов которые появились

---

1. Насколько я понял, что когда в `productFlavors` создаешь свои
   сборки вот так

   ```
   productFlavors {
   mock {
     applicationIdSuffix = ".mock"
   }
   prod {}
   }
   ```

   то , чтоб студия понимала от куда брать подтягивать изменения нужно
   создать директорию в `src` с таким же именем, именно по имени студия
   понимает что это именно так директория

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Если названия будут отличаться то студия не поймет куда идти, верно?

---

2. Хотел бы еще уточнить как студия подтягивает изменения в зависимости
   от `build variant`

   Я понял так, что за основу берется `main` и потом студия смотрит
   какой `build variant` сейчас выбран и смотрит какие классы нужно
   заменить... Но ведь названия классов отличаются.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Вот как на скриншоте допустим сейчас включена версия `mockDebug`. В
   этом варианте мы используем другой класс из папки `data` то есть
   студия должна взять за основу `main` дирикторию и понять, что
   использовать файл `FakeNotesServiceApiImpl` вместо
   `NotesServiceApiImpl` . Я полагаю что это можно понять сравнив пути
   к классам они полностью похожи, но сами имена разные... Как это
   будет работать?

   Хотя вот судя по этой заметке, файлы не заменяются как я думал, а как то по другому это работает только теперь не понятно как

> Files in the flavor-specific folders do not replace files in the main source set. Trying to do that will result in a duplicate class exception. This is a common misconception because it's how resources are merged.

---

3. И вот еще насчет случая когда нужно собрать версию для релиза я так
   понимаю, что для этого нужно в `build variant` выбрать
   `prodRelease`, но не совсем понятно от куда в таком стучае студия
   будет тянуть файлы? По логике должны собираться все файлы из
   дериктории `main`, но согласно `productFlavors` студия должна тянуть
   файлы из дириктории `prod` ... Не понятно.

   И тут же вопрос чем отличаются в структуре файлов версии допустим
   `prodDebag` и `prodRelease` если директория которая на них указывает
   одна

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   или в этом случае будут браться в учет `buildTypes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build variants это всевозможные варианты сборки вашего приложения. По умолчанию это debug и release. Можно добавлять свои варианты редактируя `buildTypes` и `productFlavors` в build.gradle вашего приложения. Все это необходимо для вынесения/добавления определенной части логики которая зависит от определенного варианта, а так же сокрытия кода, который не относится к данному варианту сборки и т.д. Так же можно разбивать по вариантам и ресурсы.

Немного распишу про [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors). Обычно они используется для:

- реализации платной и демо версии приложения;
- реализации версии приложения где взаимодействие будет вестись не с
  реальным сервером, а тестовым сервером, либо вообще будут отдаваться
  заранее подготовленные ответы;
- реализации однотипных приложений, у которых есть общая кодовая база, например взаимодействие с сервером, и индивидуальная кодовая база, которая относится к конкретному приложению, например UI.

В вашем примере это как раз второй вариант, т.е. есть две версии приложения: одна смотрит на реальный сервер, а во второй все ответы заранее подготовлены. Разные версии приложения нужны в разные моменты времени, т.е. при выпуске используется Releas вариант, при тестировании Debug, при разработке Mock. Mock вариант так же полезен, когда приложение разрабатывается параллельно с серверной частью, т.е. сервера ещё нет, а приложение уже должно общаться с ним. Тут разработчики серверной части и мобильной договариваются друг с другом на счет запросов/ответов, и мобильный разработчик просто возвращает готовый ответ.

Как это все реализовать? Для этого необходимо в `build.gradle` файле модуля приложения добавить свой `flavor`:

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {...}
    buildTypes {...}
    productFlavors {
        mock {
            ...
        }
        prod {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

После чего появятся следующие варианты сборки приложения: debugMock, releaseMock, debugProd, debugMock. Столько вариантов получается, из за того что `flavor's` как бы перемножаются с `build types`. Т.е. создаются все возможные варианты.

После этого в папке `src` модуля приложения, рядом с папкой main можно создать папку с кодовой базой для каждого flavor'a. В каждой такой папке необходимо поддерживать одинаковые структуры пакетов, не запрещается добавлять и свои пакеты, которые будут доступны только в рамках данного flavor'a. Если код из flavor'a вызывается в общем коде, то необходимо чтобы имена классов и методов в разных flavor'ах совпадали. Тогда при компиляции будет использоваться код из папки `main`, плюс код из папки конкретного flavor'a. А так как, структура в разных flavor'ах одинаковая, то код подменится корректно, приложение скомпилируется без ошибок, не будет лишнего кода, который не имеет отношения к данному приложению, и это поможет избавиться от конструкций вида(псевдокод):

```
//Где то в константе храним текущий вариант
if(variantMock) {
    //вызываем замоканную версию 
} else if(variantDebug) {
    //вызываем версию для дебага
} else if(...) // и так далее
```

**UPD:**

1. Да, надо создать папку с таким же именем, так же можно комбинировать имена flavor'ов и build types, к примеру mockDebug, mockRelease и т.д.
2. Если какие то классы используются в main пакете, например создается экземпляр объекта, то в разных flavor'ах эти классы должны иметь одинаковые имена и распологаться в одинаковом пакете, иначе в одном из вариантов будут появляться ошибки компиляции, т.к. студию не сможет найти класс по пути, указанному в импорте. Разные классы в основном пакете можно создавать через всякие фабрики, но тогда надо что бы они реализовывали какой то интерфейс, но тогда надо будет делать фабрики идентичными для разных flavor'одинаковом. Просто представьте что беруться все файлы из папки prod и копируются в папку main.
3. Ресурсы и исходные коды мержаться из папок, соответствующих данному варианту. Т.е. если выбрали prodDebug то будут мержиться папки prod + main + если есть prodDebug/debug. 
   Просто попробуйте насоздавать flavor'ов и build type'ов и переопределите в каждой из папок какой нибудь текстовый ресурс который выводите на экране, сразу все станет понятней. Папки debug/release/prodDebug/prodRelease не являются обязательными к созданию. По сути и prod можно не создавать если ничего не надо переопределять.

Comment: очень крутой ответ! Прям еще раз захотелось перечитать)) Сейчас нужно вникнуть

Comment: Я тут разобрался и появилось несколько вопросов я добавил их в вопрос. Можете помочь разобраться, а я добавлю дополнительные балы за ответ) Спасибо

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko обновил

Answer (score 2):

Вкратце, могут быть разные архитектуры, чаще всего разница в Release and Debug, практически во всех проектах, настраиваются в strucureProject,в gradle скриптах, чтоб предварительно к примеру использовать другой манифест или подключить другие либы, изменить Dependencies, изменить поведения debugger, арихвацию, подменить версию сборки, место установки и тд. Очень хорошо это дело описано в оф доках. Вопрос довольно объемный, так как на практике приходится немного больше писать, чем показывают в доках.
Вот пример, как у меня сейчас: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]